# Open Shift (minishift) and running buildConfig using bitbucket repo fails

Tags: git, openshift

I am running minishift on windows 10. When I run a buildConfig I get the below error:

```
Cloning "ssh://git@bitbucket.internal:29470/sam/my-repo" ...
error: ssh: connect to host bitbucket.internal port 29470: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Where my bc yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
kind: BuildConfig
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2018-04-24T11:31:00Z'
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-bc
  namespace: myproject
  resourceVersion: '5808'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/myproject/buildconfigs/my-bc
  uid: f68edfac-47b2-11e8-9c8e-080027ebf287
spec:
  failedBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'sample:1.0.0'
      namespace: myproject
  postCommit: {}
  resources: {}
  runPolicy: Serial
  source:
    contextDir: images/test
    git:
      ref: myfeature
      uri: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.internal:29470/sam/my-repo'
    sourceSecret:
      name: bitbucket-secret
    type: Git
  strategy:
    dockerStrategy:
      dockerfilePath: Dockerfile
    type: Docker
  successfulBuildsHistoryLimit: 5
  triggers: []
status:
  lastVersion: 16
```

and I have created a secret called: **bitbucket-secret** that contains my private key for the repo: `ssh://git@bitbucket.internal:29470/sam/my-repo` followed by running:

```
oc secrets link builder repo-at-bitbucket
oc secrets add serviceaccount/builder secrets/repo-at-bitbucket
```

Any ideas on why the buildconfig fails with a fetch error even though I specify a secret with a working private key (tested from command line)?

As suggested below I think the reason is that my pods does not have permissions to access bitbucket.internal:29470 but I can't get a pod to run and `oc rsh` to it. I get:

```
oc get pods
NAME                         READY     STATUS       RESTARTS   AGE
my-bc-14-build   0/1       Init:Error   0          18h
my-bc-15-build   0/1       Init:Error   0          18h
```

Is there a simple way to start a pod in minishift and keep it alive?

Comment: If you can deploy a application, can you use ``oc rsh`` to get into that pod and see if can connect to ``bitbucket.internal``. The error indicates that the network for your Bitbucket service is not reachable, so try some connectivity tests to see if pods running in your cluster can access it.

Comment: Yes I think you are right but I cannot seem to get a pod up and running, it just keeps hanging in the "Pod Initializing" status after it fails with the fetch error, see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

The [Openshift ssh authentication](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/builds.html#ssh-key-authentication) documentation mentions:

> Add the secret to the builder service account. Each build is run with `serviceaccount/builder` role, so you need to give it access your secret with following command:

```
oc secrets add serviceaccount/builder secrets/sshsecret
```

> Add a sourceSecret field into the source section inside the BuildConfig and set it to the name of the secret that you created. In this case sshsecret:

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "BuildConfig"
metadata:
  name: "sample-build"
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: "ImageStreamTag"
      name: "sample-image:latest"
  source:
    git:
      uri: "git@repository.com:user/app.git" 
    sourceSecret:                              <=====
      name: "sshsecret"                        <===== 
    type: "Git"
  ...
```

In your case, make sure at least to add the `sourceSecret` to your git source.

Comment: Yes I have done that as well, see details in my updated post but still the same error.

Comment: @u123 Did you try with the IP address instead of bitbucket.internal?

Comment: Yes same error, might be that I need to grant the cluster/pods access to that external server somehow.

Comment: @u123 Is it a networking issue, as in https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_load_balancer.html#load-balancer-ips-network

Comment: It probably is but before I play around with those services I would like to verify that it indeed is the case somehow